# Удалить строку в файле по слову

Tags: python

скрипт ниже удаляет строки в которых содержатся задаваемые слова
например нужно удалить строку из файла где есть слово **some**:

file.txt

```
123
some line need delete
something is ...
```

результат:

```
123
```

код программы

```
word = 'some'
f = open('file.txt', "r+")
Lines = f.readlines()
f.seek(0)
for line in Lines:
    if not re.search(word, line):
        f.write(line)
f.truncate()
f.close()
```

Как удалять те строки в котором есть целое слово **some**, не удаляя строку в которой **some** составляющая другого слова?

Comment: Или используйте регулярные выражения или пробел к `some` добавьте - `some `.

Comment: @Сергей, если добавить пробел, будут игнорироваться знаки препинания, **some,** или если будет находиться в начале или конце строки

Comment: Я немного шучу. Регулярные выражения для этого есть.

Comment: А если всё же регулярками, то если правильно помню граница слова это `\b`, т.е. регулярка для одиночных слов будет `r'\bsome\b'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А зачем применять инструмент, который в данном случае как минимум сложнее, чем самый тривиальный инструмент самого Python?

```
for line in Lines:
    if 'some' not in line.split():
         print(line)
```

Результат:

```
123
something is ...
```